# Generate LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, programmatically-created

I would like to generate some buttons items programmatically (I receive data from an API) following this mockup :

[image: I don't know how many I will receive because it's dynamic]

What is the best way to generate and populate them ? How can I use xml drawable files to be the most efficient ?

Currently, this following is how I will resolve this :

1. count = number of items % 2
2. if count != 0, number of lines equals (number_of_items/2)+1
3. for each line I will create 2 buttons into the LinearLayout

Comment: GridLayout. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).
With it setup you can adjust how much space a cell takes up and also implement an auto-fit algorithm with ease.

Comment: It seems to be the right way to do that. Thanks @TheSunny !

Comment: I have put it as an answer, upvote and accept. Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather use a GridView than a GridLayout: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Using GridView with a custom Adapter looks like to be better

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout. [See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). With it setup you can adjust how much space a cell takes up and also implement an auto-fit algorithm with ease